# IEEE style references with the article class

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I have a document with the article class. I want the references to be formatted with the IEEE style.

I used IEEEtrantools as follows:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
    \usepackage{cite} % to cite as [1-2], not [1], [2]

    \begin{document}

    \cite{einstein}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{mydatabase} 

    \end{document}
```

This does not produce IEEE style references. For example, the number field is missing. I insist on using IEEEtrantools, because it offers other useful functionalities and it's based on bibtex (not biber that does not seem as friendly).

You can consider mydatabase.bib as

```
    @article{einstein,
    title={Investigations on the Theory of the {B}rownian Movement 
    $I$},
    author={Albert Einstein},
    journal={Annal. Physik},
    volume={34},
    number={1},
    pages={591--592},
    month=jan,
    year={1911}
    }
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know why the number field is missing with the Method 2, using mydatabase example?

Comment: The package can be found here:https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools

Comment: Bibtex accepts $1\times 2$ in the title field in a bibliography item. Biber returns an error, while it prints it correctly! That produced the error I mentioned earlier. Because the output was still correct and the file was large, it was hard to find the error.

Comment: Well, I do not know/use package `IEEEtrantools`, therefore I can't tell you why number is missing.  With biblatex (your deleted version) it appears. If possible use `biblatex`, customization is easier.  Can you please add the bib entry with `$1\times 2$` add to your question?

Comment: According to the manual (p8) one should use `\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}`, although ieeetran.cls has additional definitions related to \cite.